# MenuBar Icon for Dark Mode on OS X in Java

Tags: java, macos

I can't find any information on how to set the menubar icon for dark mode on OS X (introduced in OS X 10.10 Yosemite) in Java. I've seen this post http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2014-October/006740.html but without any answer. I know this has been discussed here [How to detect dark mode in Yosemite to change the status bar menu icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379525/how-to-detect-dark-mode-in-yosemite-to-change-the-status-bar-menu-icon) for Objective-C, but not sure if this can be done similarly in Java.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I’ve had the same issue, solving it by invoking the `defaults read` command and analyzing the exit code:

```
/**
 * @return true if <code>defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle</code> has an exit status of <code>0</code> (i.e. _not_ returning "key not found").
 */
private boolean isMacMenuBarDarkMode() {
    try {
        // check for exit status only. Once there are more modes than "dark" and "default", we might need to analyze string contents..
        final Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"defaults", "read", "-g", "AppleInterfaceStyle"});
        proc.waitFor(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return proc.exitValue() == 0;
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | IllegalThreadStateException ex) {
        // IllegalThreadStateException thrown by proc.exitValue(), if process didn't terminate
        LOG.warn("Could not determine, whether 'dark mode' is being used. Falling back to default (light) mode.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can load different images and use them in a [java.awt.TrayIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html):

```
// java.awt.* controls are well suited for displaying menu bar icons on OS X
final Image image;
if (isMacMenuBarDarkMode()) {
    image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/tray_icon_darkmode.png"));
} else {
    image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/tray_icon_default.png"));
}
```

Comment: Can we do the same using python?

Comment: @ArewegoodQ Absolutely, the above isn't limited to Java. Just execute a new shell process and evaluate the exit value.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Would you mind answering this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108924/python-code-to-detect-dark-mode-in-yosemite-to-change-the-status-bar-menu-icon

Comment: For future proof, shouldn't you make sure it returns `"Dark"`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207077/how-to-detect-if-os-x-is-in-dark-mode

Comment: FYI, "Big Sur" now is capable of using "light mode" for the tray icon when the desktop is in dark mode, invalidating this answer.   New question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685948/macos-big-sur-detect-dark-menu-bar-system-tray