# Python code to detect dark mode in OS X El Capitan to change the status bar menu icon

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, osx-elcapitan, pyobjc

I have objective C code to detect dark mode to change the status bar:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(darkModeChanged:) name:@"AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification" object:nil];
```

Similarly, how can we do the same in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these following lines wherever you want to detect the mode (dark mode or light mode).

```
center = NSDistributedNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
center.addObserver_selector_name_object_(self,"enableDarkMode",'AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification',None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do this directly from within python. But at least you can invoke the terminal command `defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle`.

Currently its behavior is like this: If its exit code is 0, it reports "dark mode". If it is 1 (error), you can assume light mode. This isn't very clean in my opinion, but it works and is used successfully from a [Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33477375/4014509).

How to spawn a new process from within python is a different question, which has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/972383/4014509).

Answer (score 0):

In python `os` module may come in handy to detect the mode.

Basically, we use python to access and run terminal command to find `AppleInterfaceStyle` property in default settings.

```py
import os

has_interface = os.popen("defaults find AppleInterfaceStyle").read()
if not has_interface:
    print("Use a light Style")
else:
    interface_system = os.popen("defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle").read()
    print("Interface Style:" + interface_system) # interface_system = 'Dark\n'
```