# WxPython adaptive icon menubar for osx dark menu & light menu

Tags: python, macos, icons, wxpython

i'm creating wxPython for macOS and i add icon for menubar.
as macOS have dark mode existed, i want icon at menubar adaptive

when menubar is light color, then icon of app will black
if menubar is dark color/in dark mode, then icon of will be white

[icon when menu in light mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJfQS.png)

[icon when menu in dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eI88.png)

as you can see, icon of my app not become white when menubar in dark mode but it's grey (i set color of my app to grey)

how can i make my icon be adaptive (black when menubar in light mode, white when menubar in dark mode)?

is there feature in wxPython to make like it?

or do i need use spesific image format for icon?

Comment: You are going to need 2 icons. One black and one white. Load the appropriate icon depending on the environment, light or dark.

Comment: how i detect if macOS using dark mode/light mode from python?

Comment: Ha, there's the rub! I do not own a Mac and never have. Perhaps these two SO posts will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108924/python-code-to-detect-dark-mode-in-os-x-ei-capitan-to-change-the-status-bar-menu#37343691 and  this one for the context of putting the code together https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933107/how-do-you-listen-to-notifications-from-itunes-on-a-mac-using-the-nsdistributed