# macOS "Big Sur" Detect dark menu-bar/system tray

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, statusbar

Starting with macOS (10.16 "Beta"/11.0) "Big Sur", the menu-bar and system tray no longer honor the Desktop dark-mode preference, making it difficult to properly theme a system tray icon for this Desktop.

Previously, using a shell command `default read`, the dark mode could be detected:

```
defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle
# "Dark"
```

This still works great for detecting the Window theme, but it does not work for the menu-bar and system tray theme.

Since this area seems to be driven by the wallpaper brightness/whiteness/luminosity, how do we detect a dark system tray?

[image: n]

How to detect this in (e.g.) Objective-C/C++?  Any solution is welcome, as most can be adapted.

Question also posted to Apple Developer forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652540

Qt5.6 has a feature called [`setIsMask(...)`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/471e4fcb226c4523efe93b1bdaf0db026495da94/src/gui/image/qicon.cpp#L1341-L1355) which allows the OS to handle this automatically.  This is effectively an alias for [`NSImage::setTemplate:Yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25498025/3196753)

More references to macOS "Dark Mode":

- [How to detect if OS X is in dark mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207077)
- [MenuBar Icon for Dark Mode on OS X in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477294)

AdoptOpenJDK upstream bug report:

- https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-support/issues/146

Keywords: `NSStatusBar`, `Menu Bar Extras`

Comment: I am also very interested in a solution.

Comment: @inexcitus we've given up on getting help from Apple and started rewriting our app to use `NSImage:isTemplate`.  This is unfortunate as it requires a patch to the framework we're using. In our case, we're banking on a future Java version handling this natively. If you're also using a framework to draw the icon, you can use our code as a reference point in a feature request to whatever framework you're using: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-support/issues/146#issuecomment-697723671.  If your app is a native C++ or Objective-C app, you should consider using `NSImage:isTemplate` directly.

Comment: * correction, the API is `NSImage:setTemplate(true)` (not isTemplate).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is that I also have a NSView with text. I have opened a ticket using the Feedback Assistant. Usually Apple responds to those tickets, so fingers crossed.

Comment: `> NSView with text` 

We had to switch our code to use a button instead (technically an `NSObject` which implements `NSMenuDelegate`).  Feel free to use as much of the code as you like.  https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/compare/master...qzind:trayicon#diff-f0329dbfcfc7766bebb2bb2a071d316cL64.   I don't think Apple is going to be able to help other than recommending that you use a different API.

Comment: @inexcitus also note that the APIs we've chosen to use in the Java diffs are 10.5+ so they've been around for about 13 years and should not cause regressions.

Comment: IMHO it seems like a bug in Big Sur, might be worth submitting a feedback via the Feedback app. Hopefully it gets fixed with more people reporting it.

Comment: Several macOS releases later, is there a solution to this? the top answer by Yuji refers to a "test app" but all I see is in his repo is test code that needs to be compiled into an app. I'm looking for a simple programmatic way to detect Menu Bar mode being dark/light

Comment: Hi, OP here... since MacOS switched from light/dark to transparent menu-bar, I decided to take a different approach and let the OS decide.  In my case, this meant fixing Java at its source: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/481/files.  As a stop-gap I was able to use some special language features to force it: https://github.com/qzind/tray/pull/745.  Disclaimer: I didn't write either of these code examples.  In both instances, I hired someone to write it for me. <3

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue but I think I found a solution. As written in [AppKit Release Notes for Big Sur](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/appkit-release-notes-for-macos-11) (see the entry for `NSStatusItem`) you can just observe `NSStatusItem`'s `button`'s `effectiveAppearance`. If the name of the `effectiveAppearance` contains `dark`, then it's the dark mode. Otherwise it's the light mode.

A sample code I created which shows `light` or `dark` as the text label of the `NSStatusItem` is available at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/yujitach/nsstatusitem-lightdark-detect), see in particular [AppDelegate.m](https://github.com/yujitach/nsstatusitem-lightdark-detect/blob/main/nsstatusitem-lightdark-detect/AppDelegate.m). (I'm sorry for being a near-extinct dinosaur for using Objective-C.) You can test it by running on Catalina or on Big Sur, changing the Dark/Light settings or the color of the desktop picture from System Preferences.

Edit: It turns out that Big Sur sometimes *changes*  `effectiveAppearance` from light to light or from dark to dark (in the sense that KVO is invoked although the appearance hasn’t actually changed.) Therefore it’s advisable to check both the value of `effectiveApparance` before and after the change to confirm the value actually changed.

Comment: Way easier than my solution 

Comment: Dinosaurs are cool and so is Objective-C. 

Comment: Does this work in a case when Light mode is used on Big Sur, but background image is black, rendering the menubar black? Or vice-versa, with light background image in the dark mode?

Comment: Yes. To see it, download the test app from the GitHub repo linked above.

Answer (score 1):

I just submitted a TSI and I got an answer:

> But I would not add an NSView on top of the NSStatusItem’s button
> directly.  The docs mention to use the button property to customize
> the appearance and behavior of the status item, but it should work
> within the confines of the button itself, that is, it’s various
> properties like the image and text and their placements.  Years ago,
> NSStatusItem allowed for custom views, but then became deprecated, in
> order to support a button-based UI, therefore allowing its drawing
> behavior to easily adapt to changes in the menu bar’s appearance.

So unfortunately there is no way to get this information programatically.
However, getting information is very important for three of my apps, so I went exploring.

For me personally, it was very important that getting this information will not trigger any security prompts.

I came up with the following idea:

- Create and hide a `NSStatusItem`
- Set a templated `NSImage`
- Render the contents of the `CALayer` into a `NSImage`

You can use this code to get the colour information (note: the `NSStatusItem` is never visible and does not cause existing items to move or something like that). Feel free to adjust the formatting and classes:

I have created a class called `MenuBar` with a public property:

```
public class MenuBar {
    private static var statusItem: NSStatusItem?

    public static var theme: MenuBarTheme {
        if self.statusItem == nil {
            self.statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
            self.statusItem?.button?.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "circle.fill", accessibilityDescription: nil)
            self.statusItem?.isVisible = false
        }
        
        if let color = self.getPixelColor() {
            return color.redComponent < 0.20 && color.blueComponent < 0.20 && color.greenComponent < 0.20 ? .light : .dark
        }
        else
        {
            return NSApplication.isDarkMode ? .dark : .light
        }
    }

    public static var tintColor: NSColor {
        return self.theme == .light ? NSColor.black : NSColor.white
  }
    
  // MARK: - Helper
  fileprivate static func getPixelColor() -> NSColor?
  {
     if let image = self.statusItem?.button?.layer?.getBitmapImage() {
        let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: image.tiffRepresentation!)
            
         if let color = imageRep?.colorAt(x: Int(image.size.width / 2.0), y: Int(image.size.height / 2.0)) {
            return color
         }
     }
        
     return nil
  }
}

public enum MenuBarTheme : String
{
    case light = "light"
    case dark = "dark"
}

public extension NSApplication
{
    class var isDarkMode: Bool
    {
        return NSApplication.shared.appearance?.description.lowercased().contains("dark") ?? false
    }
}

public extension CALayer
{
    func getBitmapImage() -> NSImage
    {
        let btmpImgRep = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil, pixelsWide: Int(self.frame.width), pixelsHigh: Int(self.frame.height), bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: false, colorSpaceName: .deviceRGB, bytesPerRow: 0, bitsPerPixel: 32)

        let ctx = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: btmpImgRep!)
        let cgContext = ctx!.cgContext
        
        self.render(in: cgContext)
        
        let cgImage = cgContext.makeImage()

        return NSImage(cgImage: cgImage!, size: CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Java 17, this feature has been added.  It will eventually be backported to Java 11.

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/481

The new property is:

```
apple.awt.enableTemplateImages
```

From command line:

- `-Dapple.awt.enableTemplateImages=true`

... or via Java:

- `System.setProperty("apple.awt.enableTemplateImages", "true");`

Note, staring with Big Sur, icons aren't purely black or purely white anymore (but rather a slight shade off), so using the template API is important for proper look & feel.

Answer (score 1):

Although newer JDK versions [will have this `setTemplate` feature natively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65798511/3196753), for older Java versions, this technique uses [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) and depends on the https://github.com/dyorgio/macos-tray-icon-fixer project.  Internally, it uses a combination of Java reflection and JNA pointers to update the image and set the [`setTemplate` flag to true](https://github.com/dyorgio/macos-tray-icon-fixer/blob/6cfa7be71bea48e12683d81049e829c7bab1893a/src/main/java/dyorgio/runtime/macos/trayicon/fixer/MacOSTrayIconFixer.java#L107).

It has been tested with JDK8 and JDK11.  It will work with new Apple Silicon Macs as well if using a port of JNA with [aarch64 support](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/pull/1297).

Thanks to [@dyorgio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1125191/dyorgio) for the trick.

```
// Verify theme to choose image version
Image iconImage = MacOSTrayIconFixer.getInitialIcon(blackImage, whiteImage);
// Create your TrayIcon using image
TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(iconImage, "Test");
// (Optional) add action and menu
icon.addActionListener((e) -> System.out.println("examples.BasicUsage.main():" + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()));

// Include in SystemTray BEFORE call fixer
SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(icon);

// Fix
MacOSTrayIconFixer.fix(icon, blackImage, whiteImage, false, 0);
```